# Handling aws-sdk bucket creation requests nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following code. The main aim is to create a bucket through aws-sdk and in case of success, generate a database record for the relevant entry. But there are a few issues

```
const AWS  = require('aws-sdk');
const router = require('express').Router();

const Bucket = require("../../../models/bucket_bucket");

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

require('dotenv').config();

AWS.config.logger = console;

s3 = new AWS.S3({
    // apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});

// Accepts Bucket Name, Bucket Created User/ Belonging Organization
router.post('/create', (req, res, next)=>{

    var requestBucketParams = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucket
    }

    var isBucketCreationSuccess = false;

    var createRequestBucketPromise = s3.createBucket(requestBucketParams).promise();
    var createDeliveryBucketPromise = s3.createBucket(deliveryBucketParams).promise();

    createRequestBucketPromise.then((data)=>{
        isBucketCreationSuccess = true;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.send({
            message: "error while creating the bucket",
            description: err.message
        });
    });
    
    console.log(isBucketCreationSuccess);

        
    if(isBucketCreationSuccess){
        Bucket.create({
            bucketId: uuidv4(),
            name: req.body.bucket,
            bucket_url: "http://" + req.body.bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com",
        }).then(bucket=>{
            res.send({
                url: "http://" + req.body.bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com",
            })
        }).catch(err=>{
            res.send({
                message: err.message
            })
        })
    }else{
        res.send({
            message: "Database record creation failed"
        })
    }

});
```

So there are 2 questions that I have (Please bear with me I am not much familiar with nodejs)

1. `isBucketCreationSuccess` is always `false` no matter how I try to set it. I do believe this is something to do with async. But it doesn't work
2. This generates the following errors

```
(node:25293) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
   at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:543:11)
   at ServerResponse.header (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
   at ServerResponse.send (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
   at ServerResponse.json (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
   at ServerResponse.send (/home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
   at /home/caesar/Workspace/res-s3/res-s3-backend/routes/api/bucket/index.js:54:13
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:25293) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25293) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[AWS s3 409 2.197s 0 retries] createBucket({
 Bucket: 'delivery-bucket-1',
 CreateBucketConfiguration: { LocationConstraint: 'eu-west-1' }
})
```

Comment: I am curious, why do you create S3 Buckets dynamically? Its rather odd. Can you share the use case?

Comment: This is for managing buckets based on organizations. Such that the files uploaded could be just clustered only for the required organization, and in case we need access restrictions we can implement them based on creating IAMs

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but keep in mind S3 bucket names should be unique globally i.e. unique names across all aws s3 users. So either implement error handler for naming conflict or create names in such a way that it wont cause naming conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with Nodejs. I suggest refreshing what you know about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction)

The code that you have shared seems incomplete. I will try to explain the idea with what you have shared.

Code statements outside of the `then/catch` are executed synchronously.

```js
createRequestBucketPromise.then((data)=>{
  isBucketCreationSuccess = true;
})
.catch((err)=>{
  res.send({
    message: "error while creating the bucket",
    description: err.message
  });
});

// This will get executed before above promise handler
console.log(isBucketCreationSuccess);
```

The promise shown below doesn't have an error handler causing the warning

```js
var createDeliveryBucketPromise = s3.createBucket(deliveryBucketParams).promise();
```

You could do something like this to solve the problem but I recommend the second option i.e. using `Async`

**Using Promise**

```js
router.post('/create', (req, res, next)=>{
    // const or let is prefered over var
    const requestBucketParams = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucket
    },
    bucketUrl = `https://${req.body.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com`;

    return s3.createBucket(requestBucketParams).promise()
    .then((data) => {
        return Bucket.create({
            bucketId: uuidv4(),
            name: req.body.bucket,
            bucket_url: bucketUrl,
        });
    })
    .then((bucket) => {
        return res.send({
            url: bucketUrl,
        });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        // try to differentiate between aws error and you database error
        // and respond. There are multiple ways to achieve that
    });
});
```

**Using Async/Await**

```js
router.post('/create', async (req, res, next) => {
    // const or let is prefered over var
    const requestBucketParams = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucket
    },
    bucketUrl = `https://${req.body.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com`;

    try {
        await s3.createBucket(requestBucketParams).promise();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send({
            message: "error while creating the bucket",
            description: err.message
        });
    }
    
    try{
        await Bucket.create({
            bucketId: uuidv4(),
            name: req.body.bucket,
            bucket_url: bucketUrl,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send({
            message: "Database record creation failed"
        });
    }

    return res.send({
        url: bucketUrl,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I followed the aync/await way. But now I am getting the following error.
```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: Make sure you to define the handler function as async i.e `async (req, res, next)`

Comment: Thanks it would work. Any idea about how to deal with the error specified under (2)

Comment: The errors that you have shown are due to 2 problem 1) promise without error handler, 2) executing `res.send` multiple time.